# What is the exact form of Hubble's Law in a flat FRW universe?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion

I would like to know the exact form of Hubble's law for the luminosity distance $d_L$,
where $d_LH_0=f(z)$ in a flat FRW universe with energy density dominated by a component satisfying $\rho \sim a^{-n}$, where $a$ is the cosmic scale factor.

As I am trying to find the exact form, I don't want to use the expansion of the cosmic scale factor.

Comment: I am not sure of the definition you intend for the concept "luminosity distance". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminosity_distance . (1) For nearby objects (say, in the Milky Way) the luminosity distance gives a good approximation to the natural notion of distance in Euclidean space." (2) Calculating the relation between the apparent and actual luminosity of an object requires taking all of these factors (spacetime curvature, redshift, and time dilation) into account. (3) Another way to express the luminosity distance is through the flux-luminosity relationship.

Answer (score 0):

I think for distance you should use comoving distance, instead of luminosity distance, because on higher redshifts, luminosity distance doesn't work very well. Comoving distance is defined as:
$$\chi(t)=\int^{t_0}_t\frac{dt'}{a(t')}=\int^{1}_{a(t)}\frac{da'}{a'^2H(a')}=\int^{z}_{0}\frac{dz'}{H(z')}$$ Comoving distance work well even on high redshifts. Also, comoving distance approx to $\chi\approx z/H_0$. But in the FRW flat metric, Hubble parameter equals to: $$H(t)=\bigg(\frac{\dot{a}}{a}\bigg)$$ So It's scale factor dependent. But also, evolution of the hubble parameter can be explained as:
$$\frac{H^2(t)}{H_0^2}=\sum_{s=r,m,\nu,\Lambda}\Omega_s[a(t)]^{-3(1+\omega_s)}$$
Where $\omega_s=\frac{P_s}{\rho_s}$, $P$ is a pressure. It's so called equation of state, which was obtained from stress-energy tensor:
$$T_{\mu\nu}=\begin{bmatrix}
-\rho & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & P & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & P & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & P
\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
-\rho_\Lambda& 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 &-\rho_\Lambda& 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -\rho_\Lambda& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -\rho_\Lambda
\end{bmatrix} $$
From this tensor, $P_\Lambda=-\rho_\Lambda$, so $\omega_\Lambda=-1$. As well, for radiation $\omega_r=1/3$, for matter $\omega_m=0$.
But this equation (Hubble parameter evolution) also dependent on scale factor, as can be seen.